# Why there is no @timestamp

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana-7

Do you know why I don't see any @timestamp in my index :

```
{
  "_index": "cwl-test-20190926",
  "_type": "cwl",
  "_id": "35001503664322802044038601565960510753955487933136961536",
  "_version": 1,
  "_score": 0,
  "_source": {
    "id": "35001503664322802044038601565960510753955487933136961536",
    "timestamp": 1569521706684,
    "message": "Start my lambda",
    "level": "info",
    "lambda": "api-my-lmbda",
    "date": "2019-09-26 18:15:06"
  }
}
```

When I try to create an Index pattern I get this error:

> The indices which match this index pattern don't contain any time
>   fields.

I use Amazon Elasticsearch Service 7.1

Thanks in advance

Comment: How do you index those documents? I see a field called `timestamp` which looks like a timestamp to me... probably it's not of type `date` but `long` instead

Comment: You're right, timestamp was a long instead of iso format.
Solved with : ```document["timestamp"] = datetime.fromtimestamp(document["timestamp"]).isoformat()```